# How to share files and folders with batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to be able to share a folder on my network via batch file but I don't know how to do this. `Net Share` comes to mind but i can't seem to get it to work. I need everyone to on my network to be able to map a network drive to this particular share as it has installation packages. I don't want to have to go and type in alot of information to get the job done, neither do I want to have to do it manually. Is there any way of doing this? Also thank you in advance to anyone that can help.

Just off the top of my head i scrapped this together but couldnt get it to work.

```
@echo off
cls
net share M:\\192.168.1.103\Installations /UNLIMITED
exit
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you mixed "net share" and "net use":

On the "Server side" you will need

```
net share sharename="c:\path\to\share" /UNLIMITED
```

on the "client side" you will have to use

```
net use m: \\192.168.1.103\sharename
```

Comment: Thank you! I can sometimes firgure out the syntax but the format in cmd sytax guides are confusing for because i dont know where the spaces go or which switch to use. This fixed my problem!!

Comment: Ok now for some reason im having issues. Im trying to share the folder: C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop\Messenger and using the command "net share Messenger=C:\documents and settings\%USERNAME%\desktop\Messenger /UNLIMITED" but then instead of executing it's taking me to the output of "net share /?" Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: forgot the quotes around the path? ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax to share a folder, and also set permissions
for the user:

```
net share uncategorized_folder="C:\Users\fre_filer03\Desktop\20034\Uncategorized\" /GRANT:"fre_filer03",READ
```

Here the user "fre_filer03" is granted READ permissions to access the files
from the server.